# Is it possible to see the sha1 of deployments using jboss-cli?

Tags: wildfly

I would like to see the sha1 of existing deployments without having to open the [domain|standalone]/data/content folder.

I always know the sha1 of the war files I am deploying and I would like to check that they have been deployed successfully directly from within jboss-cli.

I'm using Wildfly version 23

Comment: Can you try this?


`jboss-cli.sh --connect
[standalone@localhost:9999 /] deployment-info --name=<deployment-name>` 

Replace "<deployment-name>" with the actual name of the deployment. This command will return information about the deployment, including the SHA1 hash.

Comment: @MusabDogan thanks but I only get name and runtime name that way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do a /deployment=*:read-resource(recursive,include-runtime) you would get it.